# React Navigation Custom Header rendering multiple times

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation-v5

I have a simple React Navigation 5 stack component. I am inserting a custom Header component into the screenOptions of the navigator like so:

```
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={ {headerShow:true, header:(p)=>
        <Header/> }}>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Notifications" component={AssetExample} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
```

My header component is quite simple as well.

```
export default function Header({
  navigation
}) {
  console.log("WHATS HAPPENING HERE")
  return ( 
    <View style = {styles.container}>
        <Text style = {styles.paragraph}>
          Something text here 
        </Text>

    </View>
  );
}
```

The console log statement in the header prints multiple times and I am unsure why that's happening.

Here is the link to the snack as well https://snack.expo.io/@mmanojr/restless-crackers

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: There is nothing wrong if you get re-renders. Until the re-render times is very high.

Comment: The question was why does it happen? Do you have answer for that?

Comment: Obvious? I see! can you point to what in the code I have shared causes that state change?

Comment: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/main/packages/native/src/NavigationContainer.tsx

https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/main/packages/stack/src/navigators/createStackNavigator.tsx

You can see this two files there are some state changes. And there is no issue with this.

Comment: I have same situation, my custom header is re-rendered 13x in average. It did not happen without Stack navigator.